# Upgrade Angular JS version 1.2.6 to Angular 16 (Material problem)

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

I would like to inform you about a project I am currently working on, which involves upgrading AngularJS version 1.2.6 to Angular 16. However, I am facing a major challenge regarding the differences between AngularJS material and Angular material.

For instance, in AngularJS material, we use the following structure:

```
<md-card-content >
Test content
</md-card-content>
```

But in Angular material, the structure is slightly different:

```
<mat-card-content >
Test content
</mat-card-content>
```

Since the material is used throughout the entire site, it would be inefficient to manually visit each page and make the necessary adjustments. Therefore, I am seeking the best approach to handle this transition and update the material structure in Angular 16.

I have installed the latest version of Angular Material and I have visited 1 to 2 pages to manually change the material tag imports etc.
I don't want to visit every page and fix it

Any suggestions or guidance on the recommended way to handle this upgrade would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Best regards,
Moh

Comment: What IDE/editor are you using. The naive approach would use something like replace all and then swap `<md` for `<mat` and `</md` for `</mat`

Comment: thanks for your response I am using VS code. but there are many tags that have changed in the latest version of the material like md-input-container to mat-form-field

Comment: I still think that search and replace are going to be your friend here. You're going to have to go through them one-by-one though. Angular JS to Angular 16 is a big change and it's going to take time.

Comment: Ok i will proceed with search and replace option thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio Code, do the following:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
2. Type in the *Search* field the following: `md-card-content`
3. Type in the *Replace* field the following: `mat-card-content`
4. Click the *Replace All* button

[image]